# Extract all text using a regex expression from project files

Tags: regex, xcode

I need to extract certain text matching a regex expression from a large number files in my xcode project. I need to place the matched text in a text file which will form part of the documentation. Is there any way this process can be automated instead of having to do a project wide search and copy on an item by item basis?

Comment: did you try the command-line command grep piping the result into a text file?

Comment: no, i am not familiar with it but seems to be exactly what I need. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the command-line command **grep** piping the result into a text file